# Editing the 'Summary' in an Atom Feed

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss, phpbb

**Background**

Linux Apache2 MySQL PhP7.0 server with PhPbb installed as the main web utility. PhPbb has an Atom feed built in.

After we remove the HTML (to make it easier to format in Discord), we get the following for both 'summary' and 'content':

> Alliance Raid Team Logs:  April 26, 2017We nearly cleared all of normal Nighthold in a single run! Actually, we probably could have if there wasn't so much amazing banter   Regardless, take a look at these logs to see if >there's anything that you can improve upon for the next round!https://www.warcraftlogs.com/reports/Cq7DGjKMtpnkNdbF/Statistics: Posted by Pink — Thu Apr 27, 2017 9:30 am

**Desired Result:**

Atom Feed from gaymerscommunity.com/feed.php to display an appropriate content for input into a Discord channel. It would be something similar to:

> We nearly cleared all of normal Nighthold in a single run! Actually, we probably could have...

The title and name appear correctly, and it does not have a 'description' section.

**The Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
{% if not FEED_TITLE is empty %}<title>{{ FEED_TITLE }}</title>{% endif %}

{% if not FEED_SUBTITLE is empty %}<subtitle>{{ FEED_SUBTITLE }}</subtitle>{% endif %}

{% if not FEED_LINK is empty %}<link href="{{ FEED_LINK }}" />{% endif %}

<updated>{{ FEED_UPDATED }}</updated>

<author><name><![CDATA[{{ FEED_AUTHOR }}]]></name></author>
<id>{{ SELF_LINK }}</id>

{% for row in FEED_ROWS %}
<entry>
    {% if not row.author is empty %}<author><name><![CDATA[{{ row.author }}]]></name></author>{% endif %}

    <updated>{% if not row.updated is empty %}{{ row.updated }} {% else %}{{ row.published }}{% endif %}</updated>

    {% if not row.published is empty %}<published>{{ row.published }}</published>{% endif %}

    <id>{{ row.link }}</id>
    <link href="{{ row.link }}"/>
    <title type="html"><![CDATA[{{ row.title }}]]></title>

    {% if not row.category is empty and row.category_name is defined and row.category_name != '' %}
        <category term="{{ row.category_name }}" scheme="{{ row.category }}" label="{{ row.category_name }}"/>
    {% endif %}

    <content type="html" xml:base="{{ row.link }}"><![CDATA[
{{ row.description }}{% if not row.statistics is empty %}<p>{{ lang('STATISTICS') }}: {{ row.statistics }}</p>{% endif %}<hr />
]]></content>
</entry>
{% endfor %}
```

That's the only .xml file I could find on the server.

**The Question**

Is there code that I can inject into a file that would shorten the summary, or can I create a 'description' section to call upon? I know my database has a "text" section for forum_posts; so, it should be possible.

Thank you for hanging in here with me. I'm pretty new to all this, but I'm learning as I go. Thank you for all your help!